# Logstash explode string to array with keys

Tags: logstash

This is my pipeline output:

```
"attributes" => "Width:150,200;Height:200;Size:L"
```

I'd like to have an output:

```
"attributes" => [
    "Width"  => [
        150,
        200
    ],
    "Height" => 200,
    "Size"   => "L"
]
```

I tried using the mutate filter

```
mutate {
    split => ["attributes", ";"]
}
```

Which transforms the data this way

```
"attributes" => [
    [0] "Width:150",
    [1] "Height:200"
    [2] "Size:L"
]
```

Is there a way to transform it via logstash filters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [kv](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html) filter:

```
kv {
    source => "attributes"
    field_split => ";"
    value_split => ":"
    target => "attributes"
}

ruby {
    # splits all fields so all fields are array
    code => "event['attributes'].each do |cusField| event['attributes'][cusField[0]] = cusField[1].split(',') end"
    # splits only if field contains ','
    # code => "event['attributes'].each do |cusField| event['attributes'][cusField[0]] = cusField[1].split(',') if cusField[1].include? ',' end"
}
```

Comment: Just a tiny addition, if I have "Width:100,150;Height..." would I be able to explode even values by comma to array?

Comment: You can conbine this with a mutate you used in question.

Comment: I get a new field name, is there a way to preserve it in "attributes" ? Also the how to target the mutation with a new fieldname (which I dont know prior to the split)

Comment: Updated my answer for preserving in "attributes". You can refer [attributes][Weight] in mutate later.

Comment: The thing is I don't know how many attributes there will be (width, height, size and maybe a hundred more) is there a way to rename the fields in some sort of loop?

Comment: perhaps I need to write that in ruby?

Comment: Nope there is an easier way i just recognized :) Check answer one more time.

Comment: Excellent! Yet one last issue with the multiple values Width:100,150,200; I need to explode them by comma.

Comment: Done. You can check again.

Answer (score -2):

You can use split directly

```
 filter {
      split {
            field => "attributes"
          }
      }
```

Here is the documentations:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.2/plugins-filters-split.html#plugins-filters-split-remove_field

Comment: The split filter splits events into multiple events